# window.history.back() not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an `<asp:LinkButton>` tag with its attribute `OnClientClick="javascript:window.history.back(); return false;"` as a part of a child. When clicked, it's supposed to work as a back button to the parent. Instead, when clicking, it takes me back to the parent page but then immediately reloads the child.

Using window.history.go(-1) gave me the same results, and I tried calling it server side using

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    Response.Redirect(prevPage);
}
```

but it didn't work either.

The child is called from the parent through a link within a Gridview in the following code:

```
protected void gvdeallocateparts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "GetDetails")
    {

        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        string reservationID = ((HiddenField)gvdeallocateparts.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].FindControl("reservationid")).Value;
        string url = "SPReserveDetails.aspx?ID=" + reservationID;
        string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=500, height=300, top=200, resizeable=yes');";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this code within the window you are opening with that script?

Comment: Yes, same window

Comment: If it takes you back to the parent page, then the button is working as you ask it to. I'm guessing something on the parent page is then directing you to the child page immediately. Do you have script running on the parent page that sends you to the child page? Does this behavior happen when you are on the child page and click the actual back button (vs the Link Button)? If it happens when you click the actual back button, then the issue is on the parent page.

Comment: Clicking the back button will load the saved cache of the page from the browser. It will not reload the page from the server. It loads it from memory and doesn't always trigger onload events either. Modern browsers in effect, retain state from memory. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Hi! maybe it's the browser (Google Chrome) I'm running the code on, but the parent page is actually a pop up window which doesn't have a back button, which is why I'm using the LinkButton in the first place. I will check my parent page for any potential causes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is returning true when you "go back".

```
if (e.CommandName == "GetDetails")
```

You're better off reloading the parent page if you want everything fresh.